# Using the Slack API, how can I direct message all users at the same time?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

On Slack, I'm aware that using `chat.postMessage` allows me to message each user individually, but how would I go about direct messaging the entire team (400 members) at once?

Comment: Get the list of all team members using `users.list` then send each one the message using a loop and `chat.postMessage`...or better yet, invite all the members to a channel using `channels.invite` and then send the message to the channel.

Comment: Well I need to individually message the users rather than send a message to the channel. Would I have to `chat.postMessage` 400 times?

Comment: Yes, of course. Two times, 400 times, it's the same amount of code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "bulk" variant of [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). So you basically need to build your own bulk message sender, which you can easily do by iterating through the list of users and sending each of them a message.

You can get the list of all users with [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list). You then have two option for sending direct messages:

1. **Slackbot channel**: Send each of them a message with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) using the ID of each user as channel.
2. **App channel**: Get the IM channel ID with [`im.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open) for each user
   and then use that as channel for [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). This only works though if you have a bot user and send the message from the bot user.

Keep in mind though, that there is a request limit of 1 message per second.

There also is a 3 seconds request time-out for many requests between Slack and your app. (e.g. for direct response to slash commands). So if your bot needs to send many messages you want to use an approach that allows you to send them asynchronously.

One solution to this problem that works very well for me is to use a messaging queue for all Slack messages sent from my bots.

Comment: When you say "iterate through the list of users," do you mean using `im.open` or `im.list`?

Comment: @thenewcoder we can talk in the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161833/slack-api

Comment: Unfortunately I need a 20 reputation before I  am able to talk.

Comment: sorry I was not aware of that rule. Lets talk here then.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, it isn't taking the channel id for a user, I put the user id in channel, still don't see any message under username but under the app only. Unable to send direct message to the user. `ChatPostMessageResponse response = Slack.getInstance().methods().chatPostMessage(r -> r
                .token("xoxb-283445553073-2837743222451-e3Y8y4cahtzeLAKIbjUHMMuC")
                .channel("A02BMMHFTSP")
                .text("Testing it!!")
        );`

Answer (score 2):

Hello For that you need a channel with all 400 of them in it, cause currently you cannot send to 400 individual users. For sending message to a channel, you just need to add channel argument for postMessage method.

Check this :: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: Currently, they're in the general channel, but I want to individually message the users instead of posting into the general channel. So from there, what should I do?

Comment: Simple add all your Users to list like ArrayList if you are using Java, then write a for loop to read one and send and repeat.

Comment: I'm actually brand new to Python also. So would I copy the code from that website as I see it or would I have to replace some?

Comment: could I email you to assist me with getting this together?