# How to message several people with a slack bot without a channel?

Tags: python, bots, slack-api

I've been working on a slack bot following [Tutorial1](https://medium.com/@julianmartinez/how-to-write-a-slack-bot-end-to-end-d6a8542c854b) and [Tutorial2](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/build-first-slack-bot-python.html) using python slackclient. I need to create a bot that can chat with several people a the same time but in a private chat, not in a groupal channel. I've tried running the bot's code several times changing the channel and it works, but I want to do it all in the same script.
Here is my code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
Token = 'xoxb-xxxxxxxxxxx.....'
usr= 'XXXXXXXX'
chat = 'XXXXXXXX'
sc = SlackClient(Token)

# c is just to exit the loop
c=0
# Initialize the bot and send a message
sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', as_user='true:', channel=chat, text='Bot is working, if you want me to sleep, just send the message \"end\"')
while c<1:
    # Get the whole conversation
    hist = sc.api_call('im.history', channel=chat)
    m=hist.get('messages')

    # Get the last message
    last_message = m[0]

    # Find who sent it
    who = last_message.get('user')

    # If the user sent the message, then find a keyword and reply something
    if who==usr:
        answer=last_message.get('text')
        if 'hi' in answer:
            sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', as_user='true:', channel=chat, text='Hello!:smiley: can I help you?')
        elif 'no' in answer:
            sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', as_user='true:', channel=chat, text='Ok, let me know if you need something')
        elif 'yes' in answer:
            sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', as_user='true:', channel=chat, text='What can I do for you?')
        elif 'end' in answer:
        c=2
```

Comment: Sharing what have you tried so far, would be a good start to better understand what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to talk privately with a user is to send a direct message by using the user ID as channel in [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). The message will then appear in the private `slackbot` channel of that user.

Alternatively you can also send messages in your dedicated app channel for a user. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781750/4379151) for how it works.

Comment: the `chat.postMessage` is working only when the input holds only 1 recipient (e.g. @FirstName.LastName)

How can the slackbot send it to multiple users at once ?

Comment: Please open a new question for your topic. TY

Comment: Actually, this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917744/using-the-slack-api-how-can-i-direct-message-all-users-at-the-same-time