# How to send bulk im messages to slack users in my workspace?

Tags: slack, slack-api

How can I send a message to multiple users using my Slack App/Bot. These are customized per user (addressed to username). Currently i loop through the list of users and do a im.open to each user and chat.postmessage to each channel.

Is there a better/efficient way to do this?

Comment: No, that is the way.

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917744/using-the-slack-api-how-can-i-direct-message-all-users-at-the-same-time/47927580#47927580