# Slack notify to user and channel with curl

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

How can I send notification using curl command to a user and channel. I know curl command but dont know how to send it to user and channel with once command.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"channel": "userid" "test-channel", "as_user": true, "text": "Passed"}' -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX" https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command is wrong, to pass a list you should have used `[]` to wrap the elements. Unfortunately it still wouldn't have worked and you would have received a `channel_not_found` error from slack, since slack would have assumed the list was the channel name.Slack doesn't have a bulk version of `chat.postMessage`. Meaning you can only send a message to one user at a time. You can find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917744/using-the-slack-api-how-can-i-direct-message-all-users-at-the-same-time)